# Проблема с Remote Debugger'ом

Tags: отладка, visual-studio

При попытке подключиться удаленно (даже не к процессу - просто к монитору), получаю ошибку:

> "Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named `domainName\userName@computerName`. The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor on remote computer does not have permission to connect to this computer."

Сразу оговорюсь: коннект происходит на DC (win2003r2) под доменным админом (машинка со студией также в домене и юзер - локальный админ), при попытке аттача монитор отписывается, мол юзер коннектед. Фаерволы выключены, локальная политика для network access: sharing security.. - classic, logon as a service - everyone.

Вопрос: в чем может быть проблема? Как решать?

**upd:** обе машинки друг-друга видят в сети (пинг <1ms).

Comment: Текст ошибки говорит о том, что удаленный монитор не может подключиться к локальной машине.    

Способ исправления - запустить монитор на удаленной машине от учетной записи, имеющей права администратора на удаленной машине и одновременно имеющей права доступа к локальной машине. 

Comment: Я же написал: юзер и так локальный и доменный админ..

Comment: Речь не о том, под каким пользователем происходит подключение, а о том, под каким пользователем запущен монитор на удаленной машине.

Comment: Аналогичный юзер, доменный админ.. "domain\user" - под ним запущен монитор, "domain\user" - под ним же запущена студия. Так же к успеху не привел runas монитора с выключенной галочкой "restricted privilege".

Comment: Ок. Тогда в комментарии.

Comment: Посмотрите неподдерживаемые сценарии: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678494.aspx#scenarios

Comment: Интересная ссылка, спасибо! Не знаю, почему сам не нашёл - как решу проблему обязательно отпишусь в чем было дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение зависит от процесса, который пытаетесь отладить.

Для native (С++, например) процессов нужно разрешить отлаживать всем (отметить "No Authentication" и "Allow any user to debug").

А для .NET приложений с точностью до наоборот - поддерживается только режим "Windows Authentication" и еще нужно указать на вкладке Permissions пользователей, которым можно отлаживать.

Comment: Приложение .net, пользователь добавлен в список.

Comment: @Дмитрий Ложкин Запустите Remote Debugging Monitor не как сервис, а как обычный процесс. Перед этим убедитесь, что в списке процессов его нет - бывает что остается. И обратите внимание, что процессов msvsmon.exe всегда несколько в памяти - удалите все.

Comment: Запускал как прцесс - не помогало. На данный момент  удалось приаттачиться к процессу, ничего не менялось - какие-то видимо внутренние причины были (если найду закономерность - напишу сюда)